# How to configure second account in single profile outlook 2007?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007

I want to configure second email address into my single profile please tell me steps.

I tried to add second email id into existing profile but i'm getting error: 
`"this account or directory type already exists and cannot be specified twice"`

please help

Comment: I guess you want 2 exchange mail account on 1 outlook profile ? I think you can't. If both mail account are on same server, you can have delegation on the other mailbox and map it on Outlook directly

Comment: actually i did it same way previously but this time i'm getting error dont know where i go wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

Are they Exchange accounts? As Mathieu has already stated, you can only have one Exchange account per profile.

However, you can open more than one mailbox in a single Exchange profile. Edit the existing Exchange account properties, go into the advanced settings and look for the 'Open these additional mailboxes' section.

Comment: not trying two exchange accounts... yone is exchange and one is pop mail account but i only want these two email ids on one outlook profile

Answer (score 0):

PS, you can add two exchange accounts in one outlook profile.
If you close outlook
open control panel
open mail
open the profile
add the second exchange account.